How to run a powershell script at logon with task scheduler as a background job
OBJECTIVES

Make a Task with Powershell which runs a Powershell script in the background without visible windows, indications, or user interaction.
ACTUAL PROBLEM

I made a code to create the scheduled task. However, when I close session to log in again and reproduce the script, it does not work.
Also, when I execute it manually in the Task Scheduler window, it runs correctly, opening a window but not closing it.
UPDATE : The window issue is solved!
CODE

AddTasks function
function addTasks {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$softwareDirectory,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$imagesDirectory
    )

    functionPresentation -text "Adding Tasks"

    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn

    $wallpaperTask = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File $softwareDirectory\changeWallpaper.ps1"
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Change Wallpaper" -TaskPath "FuckHugo" -Action $wallpaperTask -Trigger -RunLevel Highest -Force
}

This function just adds the actual script. (In the future it will add more with the same requirements)
changeWallpaper.ps1
function detectAppropriatedImages {
    param (
        [string]$imagesDirectory
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $images = Get-ChildItem -Path $imagesDirectory -File -Filter *.jpg
    $fileList = $images.FullName
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$appropriateImages = @()

    foreach ($image in $fileList) {
        $loadedImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($image)

        if ($($loadedImage.Width) -ge 1920 -and $($loadedImage.Height) -ge 1080) {
            $appropriateImages += ($image)
        }

        $loadedImage.Dispose()
    }

    return $appropriateImages
}


$imagesDirectory = "C:\Windows\Media\Garden\Wallpapers\Images"
$wallpapers = detectAppropriatedImages -imagesDirectory $imagesDirectory
$wallpaperCode = @' 
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
        namespace Win32 { 
            public class Wallpaper { 
                [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
                static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni); 
        
                public static void SetWallpaper(string path) { 
                    SystemParametersInfo(20,0,path,3); 
                }
            }
        }
'@
Add-Type $wallpaperCode

while ($true) {
    $randomImage = $($wallpapers | Get-Random)
    [Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($randomImage)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}

This file just select an appropiated image (+1920x1080) and set this image as the new wallpaper every 10 seconds.
WEB SITES VISITED

lazyadmin.nl
sharepointdiary.com
netwrix.com
stackoverflow.com
microsoft.com
sid-500.com
microsoft.com (2)
I searched a lot more websites but these are the most usefull for me.
I also asked ChatGPT or another IA but nothing worked.

In Task Scheduler, you can use the -noninteractive  flag to prevent the script from waiting on user input, which could be paired with -WindowStyle hidden.

Thank you @MF-! I tested It and worked!!
Now I just need to solve the problem about not running the script!

@mklement0 It worked for me at least about what I want, it opens and close a PowerShell window in an instant, but I do not care this tiny moment. However, If someone knows a way to not show anything, it would be a great thing to share

For options for launching PowerShell truly invisibly, see the bottom section of this answer.

@mklement0 Thank you for your response! I applied your suggestion and it worked! Now, no flashes are present using Ps2Exe module.
Thank you so much!
Removing the flag -RunLevel Highest does not work to execute the task when the user logs in :(
